# Vim with pdflatex binding produces unreadable output

Tags: latex, vim

I have the following line in my .vimrc:

```
autocmd FileType tex map <C-L> :!pdflatex % &<CR>
```

Now, the binding works fine, however when vim switches over to produces the output of pdflatex, it breaks lines in random places, producing unreadable output and making it very difficult to debug errors.  Is there any way to correct this?

Comment: Have you tried running `pdflatex` in the foreground (i.e. without `&`)?

Comment: interesting.  That fixed it.  I kept thinking it had to do with my textwidth setting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to accomplish this without anything showing in your vim session you could take a different approach. For example:

```
au FileType tex map <silent> <expr> <C-L> system("pdflatex ".expand("%"))
```

See `:help <silent>` and `:help <expr>`.

When I use `:silent !ls` the screen flashes and generally needs a redraw, so this is a workaround.

Comment: Thank you, this is also helpful.  I did want to read the output, however, to catch small syntax errors that pop up while compiling.

Comment: Probably the best option is using tmux and tslime.vim